# Cumulative NSTimeInterval of NSDates in an NSArray selected based on values in another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, enumeration

I have two arrays, one full of `NSNumber`s; the other has `NSDate`s. I am looking to iterate over the number array, and for every number that falls within a certain criterion -- let's say "is greater than 5" -- I will save that index. Then iterating over the date array I want to grab those same indexes.

Then I want to find the `NSTimeInterval` between the first and last of each set of dates, and sum those intervals

As an example:

```
NSArray *doubleArray = @[@3, @5, @6, @6, @7, @2, @8, @9, @2, @10];
NSArray *dateArray = @[dateA, dateB, dateC, dateD, dateE, dateF, dateG, dateH, dateI, dateJ];
```

In that case where every object in `doubleArray` is over 5, I would like the object at the same index in `dateArray`. So ranges 2-4, 6-7, and 10.
How would I find the time interval between the dates at the start and end of the range, then add them together for a cumulative sum? For the single items I would probably just set it a default interval time to it. In this example, I want `[dateC timeIntervalSinceDate:dateE] + [dateG timeIntervalSinceDate:dateH] + defaultInterval`

Comment: Give some sample input and output; it's not clear how exactly you want to do the accumulation. Is it `interval_B_to_C + interval_C_to_D + interval_D_to_E + interval_E_to_G + interval_G_to_H + interval_H_to_J` or is it `interval_B_to_E + interval_G_to_H + ??

Comment: Yes, output would of been good to add, it is `interval_B_to_E + interval_G_to_H`. I am assuming I would use some kind of loop to go through each interval, however I can't seem to think how I would go about doing it with intervals as each start date and end date (of each timeinterval) would have to be paired correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear, `[dateB timeIntervalSinceDate:dateE] + [dateG timeIntervalSinceDate:dateH] + defaultInterval` is the full sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of this problem, getting the dates in the second array that correspond to the objects in the first array that meet a certain criterion, is pretty easy. Obtain an `NSIndexSet` from the first array, using [`indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:)

```
NSIndexSet * indexes = [doubles indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(NSNumber * num, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                            return (BOOL)([num doubleValue] > 5);
                        }];
```

From there, you can make a new array out of the dates:

```
NSArray * selectedDates = [dates objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

If you want to add every pair of selected dates, that's a simple pairwise iteration:

```
NSTimeInterval cumInterval = 0;
NSUInteger count = [selectedDates count];
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < count - 1 /* stop before last object */; i++ ){
    NSDate * firstDate = selectedDates[i];
    NSDate * secondDate = selectedDates[i+1];
    cumInterval += [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to add only the first and last of each grouping (i.e., the interval from date B to E and the interval from G to H in your sample), then you can enumerate the `NSIndexSet`, which actually stores the indexes as ranges.

```
NSTimeInterval defaultInterval = ...;
NSTimeInterval __block cumInterval = 0;
[indexes enumerateRangesUsingBlock:^(NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    if( range.length == 1 ){
        cumInterval += defaultInterval;
        return;
    }

    NSUInteger firstIdx = range.location;
    NSUInteger secondIdx = range.location + range.length - 1;
    NSDate * firstDate = dates[firstIdx];
    NSDate * secondDate = dates[secondIdx];

    cumInterval += [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
}];
```

Comment: The code in my answer runs without an exception on your sample data. It sounds like your two arrays are not in correspondence, particularly in their length, but it's impossible for me to say for sure.

Comment: After looking back at what you written with rested eyes, yup it does work, I had  `selectedDates` from the first solution as the array for the second solution which was leading to the incorrect indexes. Thank you, I didn't NSIndexSet stored indexes as ranges learned something new :)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.